# There is a delay between the model load using gltfLoader and the scene rendering, how would I know when to hide the loading screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, gltf

I am using threejs 106 build and using `webGLRenderer` and `CSS2DRenderer` with my project.

Trying to load a `glb` model and showing a loading progress based on the `onProgress` callback of the `loader`. I hide the loading screen when the loading is 100% complete and call the renderer but rendering of the geometries take a few seconds to appear on the canvas.

How would I know the assets have been shown on the screen, so that I can hide the loading screen and not make the delay to appear before the user?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this an option https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.onAfterRender ?

Comment: This seems missing on the 3d objects with the r106 release.

Answer (score 0):

When your geometry and textures have finished loading, they only live in RAM but they haven't been passed to the GPU yet. It finally gets loaded to the GPU the first time you call `render(scene, cam)` if these elements have been added to the scene. This is usually a bottleneck that may lead to a delay. The bigger the assets, the longer the delay. My suggestion is to wait until **after** the first render finishes to hide the loading screen:

```js
onLoadComplete() {
    update();
}

var firstRender = true;
function update() {
    // This will block for a moment the first time
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Hide loading bar after the first render
    if (firstRender) {
        firstRender = false;
        hideLoadScreen();
    }

    // Subsequent frames should run smoothly afterward
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

There are some helper tools that help you pre-upload these assets to the GPU so you don't have to wait until the first frame.

- [`renderer.initTexture(texture)`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.initTexture) could be used after each texture finishes loading.
- [`renderer.compile(scene, cam)`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.compile) could be used to pre-compile materials & shaders if you have them before the geometry finishes loading.

Comment: thanks for the answer...I am doing the same thing as you told. Calling the `renderer.compile()` and `renderer.render()` from the 1onProgress` callback function as soon as the loading completes by 100% and then I have written the code to hide the overlay screen but for some reason this doesn't seem to work.

Also, the `initTexture` method seems missing on the renderer in threejs r106.

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you. If you’re using an old version that doesn’t have the feature, then its up to you to decide what to do.